# Plotting a histogram given bin endpoints and values

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

Say I have an array of bin edges, and an array of bin values. (basically the output of `plt.hist`). For instance:

```
bins = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vals = np.array([2, 5, 5, 2])
```

How do I plot this as a histogram?

Edit: for clarity, I mean vals to be the "height" of each bin, where len(vals) + 1 = len(bins)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `python 3.5` you can use `pyplot` `fill_between` function for such. You can use following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bins = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vals = np.array([2, 5, 5, 2])

plt.fill_between(bins,np.concatenate(([0],vals)), step="pre")
plt.show()
```

This will generate below graph:
[image: graph with step command]

Comment: This is not correct as it will produce a histogram using `vals` as the input `x` values, not the actual height of the bin bars as the OP requested.

Comment: You were right @Gabriel. I mistakenly understood the OP wanted to generate a histogram from the values. I updated the answer to correspond the answer to the question. I added a different option from the other answer. Unfortunately it only works for `python 3.5`.

Comment: If you want to add lines to the contour of each bar, then  `x=np.array([bins,bins,bins]).T.reshape(-1)[1:-1]` and `y=np.insert(np.array([vals,vals,np.repeat(0,len(vals))]).T.reshape(-1), 0, 0)` and `plt.plot(x,y)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [bar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) plot:

[image]

```
bins = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vals = np.array([2, 5, 5, 2])
plt.bar((bins[1:] + bins[:-1]) * .5, vals, width=(bins[1] - bins[0]))
plt.show()
```

The trick is to use the midpoints of your "edges" `(bins[1:] + bins[:-1]) * .5`, and setting the width as `(bins[1] - bins[0])` assuming that you have constant widths for your entire histogram.