# How to plot CDF or histogram using a given bins and frequency values? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a histogram data with two values. The number of sessions binned (buckets) at every 100ms. The following dataframe is sample data for reproducibility. 
How can I generate a Histogram or CDF out of this kind of data **df** ? I appreciate any help or hint.

```
import pandas as pd

no_of_session = [8228, 6269,4955,4955,3761,3627] 
buckets = [3.0, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 3.3 ]
# create empty data frame in pandas
df = pd.DataFrame()
# add a coumn
df['no_of_session']  = no_of_session
df['buckets']  = buckets
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack's answer does not take into account "buckets".

By the title of your question, you wish to plot a histogram for already given bins with counts. In this case, see e.g. related question and answer:

[Plotting a histogram given bin endpoints and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707347/plotting-a-histogram-given-bin-endpoints-and-values)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed the part about the buckets in the question!